# docker build not setting up environment variables using ENV

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, docker-build

Trying to build a docker image with golang and react code. The environment variable JWT_SECRET_KEY is not being set.

```
# Build the Go API
FROM golang:latest AS builder
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app/server
ENV JWT_SECRET_KEY=DefaultKey
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-w" -a -o /main .

# Build the React application
FROM node:alpine AS node_builder
COPY --from=builder /app/client ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Final stage build, this will be the container
# that we will deploy to production
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /main ./
COPY --from=node_builder /build ./web
RUN chmod +x ./main
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ./main
```

To build this i ran the command

```
docker build -t webapp .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `JWT_SECRET_KEY` to be set in the production stage you need to move it to that stage. Or if you need it in both copy it. So change your docker file to

```
# Build the Go API
FROM golang:latest AS builder
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app/server
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-w" -a -o /main .

# Build the React application
FROM node:alpine AS node_builder
COPY --from=builder /app/client ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Final stage build, this will be the container
# that we will deploy to production
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
ENV JWT_SECRET_KEY=DefaultKey 
COPY --from=builder /main ./
COPY --from=node_builder /build ./web
RUN chmod +x ./main
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ./main
```

Comment: How can i do that ? Shouldn't JWT_SECRET_KEY  be available when i run my container from this image ?

Comment: It's only in the first stage scope. Move it to final stage.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much !!

Comment: WOW I wish that was outlined somewhere. No where in the docs for ENV does it specify this very issue. I couldn't figure out how to set my ENV variables and when i moved them down to the final stage it all worked. Thank you!