# .NET 6 application 'Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()' not reading Dockerfile ENV set variables

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a `Dockerfile` with the following content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5020

ENV HAL_ID=62adfec0-ffff-41dd-b532-d51247f21187

WORKDIR /src
COPY Leadsly.Application.Hal.sln ./
COPY "./Leadsly.Application.Hal/Domain/*.csproj" ./Leadsly.Application.Hal/Domain/
// removed for brevity
```

In my .NET 6 application I want to grab that ENV variable to configure DI service

```
services.AddSingleton<IHalIdentity, HalIdentity>(opt =>
{
      string halId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HAL_ID") ?? "HAL_ID_NOT_FOUND";
      if (halId == "HAL_ID_NOT_FOUND")
      {
         Log.Warning("HAL_ID enviornment variable was not found or its value was not set");
         throw new ArgumentNullException("HAL_ID env variable was null but is expected to be 
         set");
      }                    

      return new HalIdentity(halId);
});
```

I can build the image successfully. Whenever I run a container from the image, the application throws the defined error. Why would that be the case?

I have also tried:

1. `GetEnvironmentVariable(string variable, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)`
2. `GetEnvironmentVariable(string variable, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User)`
3. `GetEnvironmentVariable(string variable, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)`

It isn't obvious to me what I am doing wrong. Any idea?

I also cannot view that `ENV HAL_ID=62adfec0-ffff-41dd-b532-d51247f21187`, whenever I inspect the container after running it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason was because my placement of the ENV was in the wrong stage of the `Dockerfile`. By they time the container ran those ENV variables were out of scoped.

[docker build not setting up environment variables using ENV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67853670/docker-build-not-setting-up-environment-variables-using-env)

What fixed the issue was updating `Dockerfile` to move `ENV` declarations right before `ENTRY` command

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5020

WORKDIR /src
COPY Leadsly.Application.Hal.sln ./
COPY "./Leadsly.Application.Hal/Domain/*.csproj" ./Leadsly.Application.Hal/Domain/
// removed for brevity
ENV HAL_ID=62adfec0-ffff-41dd-b532-d51247f21187
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Hal.dll"]
```